# How to sample cells of a grid (matrix) according to a Normal(Gaussian) distribution?

Tags: java, matrix, gaussian, normal-distribution, stochastic

I need to sample cells of a grid (matrix of MXN) according to a Normal Distribution in Java.

I know that [the Apache Math library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/distribution.html) has functions to sample values unidimensionally (1D), so it would be fine for a vector but I cannot find any alternative for 2D.

I have thought in using the 1D approach twice: one for rows, and another for cols. However, (1) it is not exactly appropiate since it would be using [Von Neumann distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood) and not the [geometrical distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Geometry), and (2) this approach would not avoid repetitions (i.e. it wouldn't be sampling).

So, how do I sample cells of a grid (matrix) according to a Normal(Gaussian) distribution centered in particular cell(r,c)?

---

***Alternatively***, if sampling is not possible (or too complicated), how I do distribute the probability using a Normal distribution accross cells in a grid centered in particular cell(r,c)? For example, for 3x3::

```
0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1
0.1 | 0.2 | 0.1
0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1
```

I am not sure if the previous values would actually fit any Gaussian, but more importantly, for any matrix, the sum of the cell has to be 1.

From here I can just iterate, and roll for it; or roll and iterate adding up.

Comment: Could you use polar coordinates and use the Guassian Distribution for `r` and the Uniform Distribution for `theta`? You'd have to work out how to make it fit/scale to your grid, but it might let you use the Apache library.

Comment: I am not sure who is `r` and who is `theta`, but what you are saying is: 1. Use an uniform distribution to calculate the angle, 2. Use the apache library to calculate the distance in that angle, 3. Find the cell given the direction and the angle? Mmm... geometrically it seems to make sense. It really doesn't avoid repetitions but, for now, I don't care that much. And finding the corresponding cell might be a bit of a pain, as in putting oil in old rusty gears of a bike.

Answer (score 1):

Even in the 1D case it is unclear how you are mapping a value sampled from a Gaussian distribution to a vector index; however, if all you need to do is sample a value from a 2D Gaussian, Apache commons has [MultivariateNormalDistribution](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/MultivariateNormalDistribution.html).

The diagonal entries of the covariance matrix are the variances of the Gaussian distributions along the two directions. The off diagonal entries are the covariance between the two dimensions. If the two directions are independent and both have a variance of one, your covariance matrix would be:

```
double[][] covariance =
                 {{1d, 0d},
                  {0d, 1d}};
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris, how do I use a covariance matrix? For some reason my intuition was telling me that the function would have required one parameter, the variance or sd, but it require a 2x2 matrix. I understood that the diagonal ( `[0][0]` and `[1][1]`) is the variance of x and y separatedly, but I am lost with the other values, (`[0][1]` and `[1][0]`). For what I know, the covariance matrix is symmetrical when you calculate it from data (e.g. for correlations), but here it seems that  is not required.

Comment: In any case, what would be a covariance matrix for a more or less standardized matrix, ideally in which I can use a single parameter to control the slope of the curve.

Comment: I added an example covariance matrix assuming the two directions are independent. This may not be the case for you, since the question mentions you could not independently sample two 1D distributions.